# How unfocus on jQuery for is(':focus')

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

Sorry for my poor English. 
I'm using jQuery plugin [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#ed). It contain some code

```
_isSlideOnFocus =_.$slider.find('*').is(':focus');
...
if(_isSlideOnFocus) {
    //some code that i don't want to execute
}
```

Plugin gives ability to execute callback right before upper code will execute. So i can unfocus elements, but i don't know how.

In browser console right before upper code  i try

```
_.$slider.find('*').blur();
_.$slider.find('*').each(function() {$(this).blur()});
_.$slider.find('*').trigger('blur');
```

but it don't work's.

i try in console

```
_.$slider.find(':focus'); //empty jQuery object

_.$slider.find('*').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).is(':focus')); //false for all elements
});

_.$slider.find('*').is(':focus') //but this one returns true
```

Even if I try

```
_.$slider.find('*').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':focus')) {
            $(this).blur();
            console.log($(this).is(':focus'));
        }
 });
```

console logs true, so as I can see blur is not working for is(':blur')
How can i blur all elements in $slider? Thank's for help

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/846ptuew/) the fiddle. My code in the end of js block. Subject plugin code is in the Slick.prototype.activateADA function in the end of plugin.

Comment: Trying `blur()` interactively in the console is pointless as selecting the console will likely blur any focused element. Try writing to the console, e.g.  using `console.log()`, instead.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, even this code
<!-- language: lang-js -->
_.$slider.find('*').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':focus')) {
             $(this).blur();
             console.log($(this).is(':focus'));
         }
  });

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? and please update your questions, not pasting code to comments

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436143/jquery-how-do-i-apply-blur-to-every-child-element-of-a-div-rather-than-any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I was using the old jQuery version 1.7. After updating jQuery to 1.9 blur works.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').blur();
```